# Font awesome text is not solid in Android

Tags: android, font-awesome

I am trying to show hand pointer icon which is https://fontawesome.com/icons/hand-pointer?style=regular 
I want to show it solidly(white background) like this one https://fontawesome.com/icons/hand-pointer?style=solid .
But here I have a problem that both of them has the same unicode which is **f25a**.

```
//This is the FontAwesomeTextView I Created
FontAwesomeTextView fingerPointer = new FontAwesomeTextView(MyApplication.getStaticContext());
        fingerPointer.setText(MyApplication.getStaticContext().getString(R.string.finger_pointer));
        fingerPointer.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MyApplication.getStaticContext(), R.color.colorWhite));

        fingerPointer.setShadowLayer(2,2,2,R.color.colorOrange);
        fingerPointer.setTextSize(30f);
        fingerPointer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.fingerPointer = fingerPointer;

//This is the hand pointer text that I am using
<string name="finger_pointer" translatable="false">&#xf25a;</string>
```

As you can see icon i send in link has the same unicode in string.xml.

This is my FontAwesomeTextView which is pretty simple class that loads fontawesome typeface and set it.

```
public class FontAwesomeTextView extends AppCompatTextView {


    public FontAwesomeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public FontAwesomeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public FontAwesomeTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Typeface typeface = FontCache.get(FontCache.FONT_AWESOME,getContext());
        setTypeface(typeface);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with AppCompatTextViews, but a quick and dirty test with Font Awesome 5 Free shows that the open hand is in the font with weight=400, while the solid hand is in the font with weight=900. Does that help?

Comment: AppCompatTextView is native component from Android Library. So that there is no weight attribute in it, or at least that weight does not refer to your reference